# How to multiply values from two arrays together in Processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

doing hw and faced with this problem:

"Write a function to multiply the values from two arrays together and return the result as a new array."

here is the code I have so far... everytime I try to run it in processing, however, I am faced with many error messages and I'm still not sure how my code is incorrect. If you can help I'd be extremely grateful.

```
public int weightedSum(int[5] a, int [6] b);
{
  int value;
  int sum;

  for (int i =0; i < a.length; i++)
  {
    value += a[i]* b[i];
    //sum = sum + value;
  }
  return sum;
}
int [] data; 

void setup () {
  size (500, 500);
  data= new int[5];
  data [0] = 5; 
  data[1] = 10;
  data[2] = 15;
  data [3] = 20;
  data [4] = 25;

int data [] new int[6]
data = new int [6];
data [0] = 2;
data[1] = 4;
data [2] = 6;
data [3] = 8;
data [4]= 10;
```

Comment: If you're facing many error messages, that usually means you're trying to do too much at one time. Can you try to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and post a [mcve] that demonstrates just the step you're stuck on? It's all about isolating the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Is that your complete code?  If yes, then the problem is that it is not a valid Java class.  A Java class starts with a `class` declaration.  There isn't one here.   And that is liable to result in a whole slew of compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int weightedSum(int[] one, int[] two) {
    if (one.length != two.length)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arrays should be with same size");

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
        sum += one[i] * two[i];

    return sum;
}
```

You client code could look like this:

```
int[] one = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] two = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int weightedSum = weightedSum(one, two);    // weightedSum = 130
```